# "you wouldn't know until it has happened" Is this correct?

Tags: future-tense

I want a phrase that says that a person will know about something only after it happens.

"You wouldn't know until it has happened" : Is this a correct usage? I think it's probably wrong. Can someone please help me correct the sentence?

Comment: Strictly, *You **wouldn't** know until it **had** happened* OR *You **won't** know until it **has** happened*.

Answer (score 1):

That sentence is correct and natural, but you could also say "You won't know about it....".

"Won't" expresses the basic fact. "You will only know after it happens".  Using "wouldn't" is a kind of hypothetical "You would know about it if it had happened"

Comment: What about "You can't know it until it has happened." I never see such a sentence in English, so it is unidiomatic, but I wonder whether there is any situation where we can use "You can't know it."